# Any Ideas or suggests on data transformation to better suite a boosting or ML model

Tags: data-mining

I want to create a model to determine gender from the device information and what apps they have used. Right Now I have A set of data approximately 100000 that looks in approximately like this for each device that we get data from.

```
- Device ID: 3hfs83478hdfvsdfn (a hash)  
- Apps Used: com.uber:4,com.amazon.purchase:5(url of the app plus the amount of 
  times the app sent a package with information.)
```

I have thought about using a simHash and feeding it into a Boosting model but the results were not great. I think simHash might be a little bit to brutal, does anyone have any suggests about how I can better manipulate the data to get more information out of it?

Comment: Do you have any ground truth for the gender of the device owner/user, or literally just large amounts of the device and apps data that you show?

Comment: Yeah we have the true gender I am trying to train a model that can predict it

Comment: do you have name of users ??

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

I would have first created an ontology holding a list of all apps used in your data set. Using the ontology and the data I would have vectorized each device into categorical features(has/has not) of each of the apps.

Then, I can use a KNN based on a cosine-similarity metric-space of prediction.

I am not sure how many apps (bits) the vector will be comprised of, so you might need dimensionality reduction or a more robust classification algorithm (maybe SVM since it can handle lots of features).